# Expected RBRACE and Unexpected token '}'

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to edit a post's CSS in Wordpress theme editor, however, I get two errors. Here is the code:

```css
#post-6303 {
  .post-content {
    padding: 0 10% 0 10%;
  }
}
```

The second line gets `unexpected RBRACE` and the last line gets `unexpected '}'`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

It is invalid syntax if you use `css` without any preprocessors.

There is valid code:

```
#post-6303 .post-content {
  padding: 0 10% 0 10%;
}
```